# Azure Web App: activate application logging for more than 12 hours

Tags: node.js, web-services, azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible keep application logging active for more than 12 hours for an Azure Web App?

I have a deployment with Node.js which runs randomly into DB connection issues that I can not trace down as they happen only every 2 or 3 days. For debugging reasons I would like to have the logging output for that issues but I did not found a way to do so? Did anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

You can do this by setting an **app setting** called `DIAGNOSTICS_TEXTTRACETURNOFFPERIOD` to a value (much) greater than `12 * 60 * 60 * 1000` which is 12 hours in milliseconds.

[source](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#diagnostics-related-settings).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to utilize an [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/insights-perf-analytics/) instance. You can enable this via a site extension or by incorporating the SDK into your Node.js code. Today, you automatically have an app insights instance created with the same name as your web app, however, you may need to manually create one depending on how long ago you created this web app.

SDK:

```
npm install applicationinsights
```

In your app.js/server.js file:

```
import appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("<instrumentation_key>").start();
```

More info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights