# How to I read and write to console in Azure in .Net framework over a long period of time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, appinsights

We have a .net framework 4.5.1 MVC web application. We want to log information to the console when the application runs. Obviously when running the app in my local computer, I can see the output window and my logs are there. But what about when it's deployed to Azure? How do I see my logs? Where in Azure should I log to (or what are my options)?

I tried:

- Log streaming, but that lets me read logs for 12 hours then auto-shuts off. I need to see logs from a long time ago.
- Azure App Insights, but I couldn't find any log information in there.
- Log Querying, where it shows me a SQL-studio-like interface. But it says there's no logs, and sometimes it's grayed out and I can't enter a query, not that it shows anyways.
- Using these logging tools:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(" Console.WriteLine");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(" Trace.WriteLine");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(" Trace.TraceInformation");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning(" Trace.TraceWarning");
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(" Trace.TraceError");
```

But I can't find my logs anywhere except in log streaming, which isn't what I'm looking for since that only works for 12 hours.

Comment: Use Serilog and/or M.E.L.. Don’t write to stdout for logging. Yes, you can use MEL in .NET Framework 4. But you should update to .NET Framework 4.8 first. Why are you still running 4.5.1? **4.5.1 is obsolete and unsupported**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to repro in my local and i can able to see my logs through:

. [Enable diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)

.[Download Logs from Kudu console](https://www.gslab.com/blogs/kudu-azure-web-app)

From Diagnostic setting i have enabled the following to see the logs

[image]

[image]

From Application insight we can see below data for our application
[image]

And , Using **KuduConsole** we can download the log files . From app service >**advance tools**> click on **GO**

[image]

After open kudu Go to `**Debug console**` and from here we can download our logs from the Left side as marked:

[image]

> But I can't find my logs anywhere except in log streaming, which isn't
> what I'm looking for since that only works for 12 hours.

Also Thanks to [Amit Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1748251/amit-apple) posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795040/azure-web-app-activate-application-logging-for-more-than-12-hours) as an answer to help other community members.

"You can do this by setting an **App setting** called `DIAGNOSTICS_TEXTTRACETURNOFFPERIOD` to a value (much) greater than `12 * 60 * 60 * 1000` which is 12 hours in milliseconds."
as mentioned in [GItHub](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#diagnostics-related-settings)

For further information Please refer this SO thread [How can I view console or trace output in an azure app service? Console.WriteLine or Trace.TraceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696690/how-can-i-view-console-or-trace-output-in-an-azure-app-service-console-writelin)